Apache Airflow build via docker-compose Web UI still presenting UTC
I am using docker-compose to build Airflow.
I have read the official docs to revise the timezone here.
This is my file:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: 'Europe/***'
    # AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: 'Europe/***'
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: ''
    TZ: 'Europe/***'

I read original you have to set AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE then saw if you leave it blank it picks up with core default.

So the Server time zone updates, but the default UTC timezone remains.
When I use docker exec -it <container> bash to look into one of the containers and use env I can see the ENV variables are set.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Here is airflow Configuration Reference link

To set AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE = "" is Default UTC
 NOT core default.
